# Why does my custom member variable of a class not update in other classes?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, scope, static

So I'm working on a project and I need to design a game that has a player. Inside the Game object, I've initialized a player and set a getter for this player:

[image: Player declaration]
[image: getPlayer method]

The player knows only of its own settlements.  Whenever I found a new settlement, the settlement should be added to that specific player's settlements arraylist.  So, inside the player class, I've initialized an arraylist of settlements, and a method that adds a settlement to that arraylist.

[image: Player's settlements array]
[image: AddToSettlement]

When I write a test for multiple found settlement calls, the settlements that I add are not persisting outside of the function call inside of my Game object:

[image: found settlement]

I know this is some scoping or static declaration error of some kind, but I don't understand why my implementation wouldn't work.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is perhaps a better example of what isn't passing.

```
map.foundNewSettlement(new Coordinate(1,1));
map.foundNewSettlement(new Coordinate(-2,3));
System.out.print(map.getPlayer().getSettlements().size());
```

The size that is printed is 0 when it should be 2

Comment: Please do not post text/code as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance fields are reinitialized at each test method launched.
So `game` instance is not persistent between test methods.
If the second test is testing that "adding a second settlement" works, you should first add a settlement (that is create the initial context of the test) before calling the method to test : `addSettlement()`.

Besides, a test method should not rely on previous side effects performed by another test method.
 Keep your test methods independent to keep it isolated and maintainable.

So, you should create the initializing context for each tested method. 
At the beginning, you can perform this task directly in the tested method. 
Later if you start to repeat yourself concerning initializing context, you may introduce private method to do it.

Here is a very simple example to show how to create the context with JUnit :

```
private Game game;

// executed before each test method
@Before
public void setup(){
    Game game = new Game();
    game.addPlayer(new Player(...));
}

@Test
public void addASecondSettlement(){
    // context
    game.getPlayer().addSettlement(new Settlement(1));
    // action
    game.getPlayer().addSettlement(new Settlement(2));
    //assertion
    Assert.assertEquals(2, game.findLastSetllement().getId());
}
```

Comment: I've added the tests to be an example of different code in my program called "found settlement" that exists as its own function in the game.  After my "found settlement" function is called, the player's settlements array should contain the new settlement, but it isn't persisting.  I've changed the test code to my implementation of found settlement.

Comment: Because the `game` instance is not persisted after the first test and the ArrayList of settlement is contained in `game`. Changes performed by the test are not kept between two tests.

Comment: You're definitely right, I should've taken more care when writing those mock tests, but consider this: I have an acceptance test that "founds" multiple settlements.  In this one acceptance test, the founding of settlements is not persisting.

Comment: I updated with a sample to show how create a context in this case.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far. I'll edit my post to show a different test that isn't passing

Comment: Sure it will not pass. just look at your comment `// executed before each test method`. that is exactly what happens. You have `new Game()` with one `new Player` in it each time. So, you did exact the same as in first time. BTW: it is better to do not replace initial code in question. It is not a chat and it misleads others from answers context.

Comment: @Vadim Okay sorry, I'll just close the question as david had the correct answer to the original question posted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @davidxx answer:

you can use static game variable in your test:

```
private static Game game = new Game();
```

or if you need more actions to do ahead use `static` block

```
    private static Game game;
    static
    {
       game = new Game();
       ... do more preparations ... 
    }
```

or more correct JUnit way to have a `@BeforeClass` annotated static method

```
private static Game game;

@BeforeClass
public static void init()
{
    game=new Game();
    ... do more preparations ... 
}
```